# StructureMap for same interface but with multiple instances for different constructor parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I'm struggling with StructureMap. I need to ensure that i get an instance per `HttpContextLifecycle` but one for each constructor parameter. Our old working code was:

Registry:

```
For<IGenericFormInitialValueResolver<SalesforceEditContactBlock>>()
    .LifecycleIs<HttpContextLifecycle>()
    .Use<SalesforceEditFormInitialValueResolver>();
```

In `FormInitialValueResolverFactory`(actualType is the `IGenericFormInitialValueResolver` generic type):

```
if (_iocContainer.TryGetInstance(actualType) is IGenericFormInitialValueResolver returnValue)
{
    if (returnValue is ISalesforceInstanceFormInitialValueResolver salesforceInstanceFormInitialValueResolver &&
        salesforceInstanceName.HasValue)
    {
        salesforceInstanceFormInitialValueResolver.SalesforceInstanceName = salesforceInstanceName.Value;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Now i need to change it, so that the `SalesforceInstanceName` is given in the constructor. But i still want that for each `SalesforceInstanceName`(it's an enum with 2 values) the instance is cached for the `HttpContextLifecycle`. So i passed the parameter via `TryGetInstance` overload:

```
ExplicitArguments args = new ExplicitArguments();
args.Set(salesforceInstanceName ?? SalesforceInstanceName.Undefined);
if (_iocContainer.TryGetInstance(actualType, args) is IGenericFormInitialValueResolver returnValue)
{
    return returnValue;
}
```

That worked in a way that i got the instance but always a new one, so it's not cached per http lifecycle.

So i have tried to change the registry:

```
foreach (SalesforceInstanceName salesforceInstanceName in (SalesforceInstanceName[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SalesforceInstanceName)))
{
    For<IGenericFormInitialValueResolver<SalesforceEditContactBlock>>()
        .Add<SalesforceEditFormInitialValueResolver>().Ctor<SalesforceInstanceName>()
        .Is(salesforceInstanceName)
        .LifecycleIs<HttpContextLifecycle>();
}
```

But now `TryGetInstance` always returns `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StructureMap by design will always build a fresh instance if you pass custom constructor parameters via `ExplicitArguments`. You might want to use named instances instead like this:

```
foreach (SalesforceInstanceName salesforceInstanceName in (SalesforceInstanceName[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SalesforceInstanceName)))
{
    For<IGenericFormInitialValueResolver<SalesforceEditContactBlock>>()
        .Use<SalesforceEditFormInitialValueResolver>()
        .Ctor<SalesforceInstanceName>()
        .Is(salesforceInstanceName)
        .Named(salesforceInstanceName.ToString())
        .LifecycleIs<HttpContextLifecycle>();
}
```

You basically say that for each value of `SalesforceInstanceName` enum you register separate named instance (with name of said enum value) of `SalesforceEditFormInitialValueResolver` with that enum value as constructor argument.

Then to resolve, instead of using `ExplicitArguments`, use name:

```
container.TryGetInstance(actualType, salesforceInstanceName.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will test it now. Meanwhile i have found a different working approach(see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69769433/284240)). I guess yours is more efficient and cleaner isn't it?

Comment: I think so. For example, since you want to cache those instances - they are somewhat expensive to construct. And in your approach you always construct all 3 (by resolving all 3), even if you need 1. In my approach only one is constructed.

Comment: You're right, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I had already a working solution before i saw [Evk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69769207/284240)(which i will check now):

```
IGenericFormInitialValueResolver genericFormResolver = _iocContainer.GetAllInstances(actualType)
    .OfType<IGenericFormInitialValueResolver>()
    .FirstOrDefault(resolver => resolver is ISalesforceInstanceFormInitialValueResolver sr && sr.SalesforceInstanceName == salesforceInstanceName);
if (genericFormResolver != null)
{
    return genericFormResolver;
}
```

So i'm using `iocContainer.GetAllInstances` to get all(3) instances and then filter the one i need. I guess Evk's approach is cleaner and might me more efficient.

Update: i tested Evk's approach and it's working fine. I get always a cached instanced for each `SalesforceInstanceName` and what makes it better than mine is: only the instance needed is constructed and not all. I keep this answer in case someone needs an alternative.